# PHP web application performance measurement tool

Tags: php, web-applications, jmeter, performance-testing, lumen

Need some web application performance measurement tool.. Can you guys suggest me some better ones..

Purpose: First, app is built on Lumen and Dashboard is built upon Laravel. So why I want something is to measure all requests performance to app and then I can to note down results of each and every requests' time consumption, based on that app can be optimized in better way

I did some google found JMeter is most of the people's choice, as its from apache and does the job but it looks lil complex, also found https://locust.io/ interesting, that I'm gonna give it a try

But I would more like to get experts suggestions or advice on this

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is [quite a number of free load testing tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) and the absolute majority of them supports [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol so feel free to choose any.

Regarding JMeter and Locust, if you can develop code in Python - go for Locust as you won't have to learn new things and will be able to start right away.

If your Python programming skills are not that good I would recommend reconsidering JMeter as it is not that complex at all:

- JMeter is GUI based so you can create your test using mouse.
- JMeter comes with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) so you will be able to create test plan "skeleton" in few minutes using your favourite browser
- JMeter supports way more protocols, i.e. you can load test databases via JDBC, mail servers via SMTP/IMAP/POP, MQ servers via JMS, etc. while Locust is more HTTP-oriented, if you need more - you have to code

If above points sound promising check out [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/learn-jmeter-for-free-launching-the-jmeter-academy) - the fastest and the most efficient way of ramping up on JMeter as of now.

Answer (score 2):

XHProf you can use it check every function exec time! it can show you with a web gui!

https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof

XHProf is a function-level hierarchical profiler for PHP and has a simple HTML based navigational interface. The raw data collection component is implemented in C (as a PHP extension). The reporting/UI layer is all in PHP. It is capable of reporting function-level inclusive and exclusive wall times, memory usage, CPU times and number of calls for each function. Additionally, it supports ability to compare two runs (hierarchical DIFF reports), or aggregate results from multiple runs.